# UIWebView incorrect content height

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, uiwebview

I'm trying to resize a `UIWebView` so that it fits the entire contents of the loaded page. To do this, I get the content height of the webview's scrollview, and set the height of the webview to that value.

For anything with content height over 200, this works just fine, and the view scales to exactly fit the page without any extra space.  But with content of height under 200, the webview seems to hit some sort of height floor, and `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height` won't return any values under 200.  I'm left with a ton of whitespace.

There are a number of posts on this topic, but none seem to cover this particular issue.  What is the best way to return the actual content height when that value is under 200?

EDIT: Here's an example of HTML that should render quite short, but ends up being 200pt tall.

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=yes'>
<html>
<head></head>
<body style='font-family:Helvetica neue; font-size:1.0em; color:#181818; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;'><div>
Here's some example content.
<br/></div>
</body>
```

Comment: maybe you have a CSS rule like `body { min-height: 200px }`?

Comment: @Michael, please see edits above

Comment: when do you fetch the `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height`? in your `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate method or at an earlier point in time? ([why I'm asking...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23921051/754705))

Comment: @Michael I fetch the height once the content has finished loading.

Comment: ok, then I don't know...

Comment: fwiw, this may be fighting with autoLayout. try disabling and/or see what sizes look like in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: I ended up coming up with a slightly more complex process of walking the dom to determine the minimum display height for content.  Still a work in progress.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that both your `HTML` and `BODY` tags **do not** have a `min-height` or `height` css styles.
Then, you should take the height using JavaScript. To get the *actual* height, instead of the *scrollable* size which is some kind of unknown UIWebView decision.

So `[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.offsetHeight"] floatValue]` would do.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem where I was using a javascript call to get the content height and setting the web view's height to that value, but 568 seemed to be the minimum that those methods would return to me. I ended up having to first set my web view's height to 1, and then set the height to the result of the javascript calls.